# Objective-c login to google and get user bookmarks

Tags: objective-c, google-chrome, authentication, synchronization

I'm working on a web browser for iOS and I'm trying to add google chrome sync for bookmarks. I've seen a few ps do this, like the chrome app and Mercury web browser. I can't find anything for the API to retrieve the bookmarks.